# Script only works after opening browser and closing it

Tags: bash, script

I have a script to open 2 webpages one on each monitor. The end of the script selects one of the pages and enters in login credentials. The script works great and I have it working with systemctl to auto start on reboot. The problem is the script seems like it ignores some lines (seemingly at random) after a reboot of my pi. This happens whether I am using the systemctl or not.

***Edit***

The line it seems to ignore most is one of the more important ones for the login function to work.

```
xdotool search --name 'Login'>xdotool windowactivate
```

I also tried windowfocus which works normally but not after a reboot.

***End Edit***

Troubleshooting that I did:

- **Waiting a long time after rebooting** - This didn't work
- **Opening a browser and closing it after reboot then running script** - This worked
- **I added sleep commands in between opening the browsers** - The browsers open simultaneously after a reboot ignoring the sleep command. However, if I close the browsers and run the script again the sleep command works and 1 browser opens then the other one after the sleep.
- **Added at the beginning of the script to open a browser and then close it and then continuing the script** -This didn't work. Almost as if ignoring the opening and closing of the browser? I tried buffering the 2 commands with sleep but it ignored those as well.

Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
xset s noblank
xset s off
xset -dpms

unclutter -idle 0.5 -root &

sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium/Singleton*

/usr/bin/chromium-browser --new-window --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk --user-data-dir="/tmp/1" --window-position=0,0 'http://ExampleDisplay.com' &
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --new-window --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk --user-data-dir="/tmp/2" --window-position=2500,0 'http://ExampleLogin.com' &

sleep 7
xdotool search --name 'Login'>xdotool windowactivate
sleep 2.5
xdotool type 'TEST' # CHANGE THIS FOR DIFFERENT LOGIN
sleep .2
xdotool key 'Tab'
sleep .2
xdotool type 'TEST' # CHANGE THIS FOR DIFFERENT LOGIN
sleep .2
xdotool key 'Return'
sleep 4
xdotool type 'TESTORG' # CHANGE THIS FOR DIFFERENT ORGANIZATION
sleep .2
xdotool key 'Tab'
sleep .2
xdotool key 'Tab'
sleep .2
xdotool key 'Tab'
sleep .2
xdotool type 'TESTSTATION' # CHANGE THIS FOR DIFFERENT STATION
sleep .2
xdotool key 'Return'
```

Lastly, here is my systemctl (this shouldn't be needed because it happens regardless of using the systemctl, but just in case)

```
[Unit]
Description=Chromium Kiosk
Wants=graphical.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/kiosk1.sh
Restart=on-abort
User=pi
Group=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: why are you limiting your chances of getting a good answer by posting here? ... your question is linux related

Comment: @jsotola I'm new to posting on forums. I can usually find an answer through searching other peoples questions but haven't had any luck. I thought I'd start here because when troubleshooting with other things it seemed the Rasbian OS acts different about certain things because it is a ARM processor instead of a x86 processor. I can post in a Linux forum as well if you think I might have a better outcome.

Comment: there are some conversations on the web about the xdotool ... maybe it not work as you expect